# change/set new value in column of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Here is my code :

```
protected void CallCardStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var thisRow = e.Row;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

         switch (thisRow.Cells[11].Text)
         {
              case "MBMK":
                        thisRow.Cells[9].Text = "JBPM MELAKA";
                        break;
              case "IPBJMA":             
                        thisRow.Cells[9].Text = "JBPM KUALA LUMPUR";
                        break;
              case "JBPMBJ":
                        thisRow.Cells[9].Text = "JBPM SELANGOR";    
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
           }

      }
 }
```

here is the a part of markup for my gridview.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="CallCardStatus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowDataBound="CallCardStatus_RowDataBound" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    OnRowCommand="CallCardStatus_RowCommand" 
    DataKeyNames="call_card_no" Width="100%" 
         <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="call_city_desc" HeaderText="City" 
            meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource4">
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Groove" 
                BorderWidth="4px" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" Font-Size="Large" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" BorderColor="#999999" 
                BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Size="10pt" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="owner_department_code" HeaderText="PSCC" 
                    Visible="False" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want to change value in the gridview. I had tried the code above but it's not working. Kindly please help..Siti..:)

Comment: What does your grid look like? Have you set `AutoGenerateColumns=true` or are you using BoundFields/TemplateFields? Show us the markup.

Comment: is the breakpoint entering any case statements ?

Comment: I agree change the default to be something like default:
 thisRow.Cells[9].Text = "Testing"; 
                        break;

Comment: Tim Schmelter, AutoGenerateColumns=false.

Comment: MVCKarl, the switch statement actually working correctly but in gridview its not display the new value that I have been set.

Comment: @Siti Ok now put thisRow.Cells[9].Text = "XYZ"; in the 'default:' part of switch.and see the change in gridview,This tells that switch condition is never met.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try putting the Default value in and see if that comes up as we have suggested. We believe that none of those conditions are being hit and thats why you aren't getting any changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your logic in code behind method and call that method as follows:

if you are using template filed then call method as follows:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column_Name" SortExpression="Column_Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
      Text='<%# YourMethodName(Eval("DatabaseFiledName")) %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Or if you are using boundField Then

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="<%#YourMethodName(Eval("DatabaseFiledName")) %>" HeaderText="Column_Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column_Name"/>
```

and your code behind method will be:

```
public string YourMethodName(object strValue)
 {
    string retString ="";

   switch (Convert.ToString(strValue))
     {
          case "MBMK":
                retString "JBPM MELAKA";
               break;
          case "IPBJMA":             
                   retString = "JBPM KUALA LUMPUR";
                    break;
          case "JBPMBJ":
                   retString  = "JBPM SELANGOR";    
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

          return retString;
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is data field name.